# node theming doesn't work

Tags: theming, nodes

I am a Drupal beginner. I'm using Drupal 7. I created a blog using views. I'm trying to theme the blog node using `node--blog.tpl.php` but it doesn't work. When I change it to simply `node.tpl.php` it works. I don't know what is the problem. How can I make it work?

Comment: Clear Drupal cache .. It should work..

Comment: I cleared the cache and it didn't work.

Comment: When you say, "created a blog using views," are you trying to theme a teaser or other view of a node displayed in that view?  If this is the case, the template name should be `node--view--NAMEOFTHEVIEW.tpl.php` or `node--view--NAMEOFTHEVIEW--NAMEOFTHEDISPLAY.tpl.php`...

Answer (score 0):

That's a known issue in some Drupal versions: Drupal will not pick up node--blog.tpl.php from your theme directory unless there is node.tpl.php too. Just place them both in your theme, clear cache, and you should be fine.

Comment: I placed them both in my theme, cleared the cache, and didn't work.